# How to find row number of some value ignoring case in python

Tags: python, dataframe, text

I have a big xlsx file that contains emails,as well, text file with lots of emails.
I want to know if each email in my txt file is in the xlsx.
So I transformed the xlsx file into pandas df and made list from email adresses I have.
 I know how to find the row number per wanted value.
My problem is: that sometimes the emails are written with capital letter.
For example in df written:    Email@GMAIL.com
and in my list of emails: email@gmail.com
So the program see these email as two different.

How can I ignore the case?
I'm self learning and glad to get some help
I'm sorry for grammar mistakes.

```py
for email in search_list:
#returns  list with numbers of rows per specific email where it appeared
      rows_per_email = list(df.loc[df['E-mail'] == email].index.values)
```

Comment: use `str.lower()` to lower both cases

Comment: I already read about this solution, but have no idea where exactly should I use this

Comment: Use it to lower the string you get from the file as well as the list

Comment: Maybe try:  `rows_per_email = list(df.loc[df['E-mail'].lower() == email.lower()].index.values)`

Comment: This is something I have tried before.But series obj has no attribute lower

Comment: Strange but for me, `df.loc` gives string

Comment: Which python version is it? 2 or 3?

Comment: Notice, I have double []
So .lower() is on df['E=mail'], and this is column.I cant use .lower() on the loc in this case.

Comment: Can you please provide some more of the sample code? Like testable?

Comment: I changed df['E-mail']  to df['E-mail'].str.lower()
and it did the job.Thanks you any way!

Comment: Please prefer answering your own question

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```py
df['E-mail'] to df['E-mail'].str.lower()
```

and it did the job